# What is the JScript version that's in IE9?

Tags: javascript, chakra

I want this for some [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kx09ct1(VS.80).aspx) code that will run in all IE's less than IE9.

Comment: fwiw, conditional compilation will be in IE10's JScript engine.  https://twitter.com/CarterRabasa/status/103241784137756673

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The check for less than IE9 is:

```
if (@_jscript_version < 9)
```

It's worth noting, the wikipedia crowd keeps these updated pretty well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

Comment: Interesting! I'm glad that IE will be keeping the JScript version in sync with the product version from now on.

Comment: Yep they separate IE9's JavaScript engine from the system JScript engine.

Answer (score 4):

It is almost always better to do feature detection, not specific version (or specific browser) detection, because there's no certainty that a given version of a browser is always the same.

For example, Microsoft will release a new mobile platform soon, with its own version of IE. In the past, the mobile versions of IE have sometimes reported exactly the same version data as the desktop versions, but they've had very different features and quirks between them.

I'd also suggest using jQuery, Modernizr, and other tools to make it easier to write code without having to worry about which browser you're on.

Comment: Modernizr and jQuery are indeed quality products. :)

Comment: Haha. Hey Paul, maybe if you try the contact forms on their webpages you could get in contact with a team member from one or both of those projects. I hear Paul Irish is on both teams, so he might be a good person to ask!

Comment: I wish I could favourite comments

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, i too think that feature detection is the safest bet.
you might also wanna keep an eye on the ecma support that particular jscript versions offer..

For IE 9 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705.aspx

And John resig's post..
ejohn.org/blog/versions-of-javascript/